# Previous and Next buttons?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn how to add a next and a previous button for the listed images that I have set plan and I don't know why it's not working. I tried following the tutorial from w3schools listed here
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_next_prev

I've seen many tutorials on slide projects using JavaScript but that didn't help. What I want mine to look like is to add a Previous and a Next button for every 4 horizontal rows of image (16 images total) but after multiple trys I still can't get it to work. I'm a beginner wanting to learn as I go and I was wondering if anybody could help me with this. Thank you!

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<span id=HOME></span>
<html>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css.css">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

  

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#HOME">HOME</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#myBtnContainer">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>

  </ul>

</nav>


<!-- MAIN (Center website) -->
<div class="main">

<h1>test</h1>
<hr>

<h2>test title
</h2>
</span>
<img src="guy.png" alt="Italian Trulli">
<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> All Products</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('2')"> test2</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('3')"> test 3</button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('4')"> test 4</button>
    <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('5')"> test 5</button>
      <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('6')"> test 6</button>
        <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('7')"> test 7</button>
</div>

<!-- Portfolio Gallery Grid -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="pic/1.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/2.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/3.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%">

    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column 4">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="pic/4.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/5.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/6.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="pic/7.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/8.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/9.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/10.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/11.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/12.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/13.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/14.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/15.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/16.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!---next and previous--->
  
    <a href="#" class="previous">&laquo; Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="next">Next &raquo;</a>

<a href="#" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
<a href="#" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
    <!---next and previous--->
  
  
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/17.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/18.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/19.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/20.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/21.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/22.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/23.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/24.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/25.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column ">
    <div class="content">
    <img src="pic/26.jpg" alt="Car" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    
  </div>
<!-- END GRID -->
  
</div>



  
  
<hr>
<h1>test</h1>
<footer> <small>&copy; Copyright 2020,  test</small> </footer> 
<!-- END MAIN -->
</div>

<script>
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container-1{
  display:flex;

}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
  50% {
      background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
      background-position: 0% 50%;
  }
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;

}
body,
html{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  
}
nav{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10$;
}

ul{
  padding:0;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-image: none;

}

/* Center website */
.main {

  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 90px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px -16px;
  
}

/* Add padding BETWEEN each column */
.row,
.row > .column {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 22%;
  display: none; /* Hide all elements by default */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Clear floats after rows */ 
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Content */
.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

The codepen is listed here to view my code
https://codepen.io/freedom1060/pen/VwaKEaJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question why the buttons are not working:

- if you meant to use JavaScript/jQuery for it to work, it's because there's no code that's "watching" for the [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) of "Previous" and "Next"' and [manipulating the HTML DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) (i.e. changing `src` path of images in your current page) to display different images
- if you meant to play around with basics and would like to use plain HTML for it to work, you could have multiple HTML pages with each page containing max of 16 pictures with right `src` path for images, and have path to those HTML pages hard coded in each of those page, something like this `<a href="page0.html" class="previous">Previous</a>` `<a href="page2.html" class="next">Next</a>`

---

A side note, noticed you have two `<h1>` in your code, which is not the best practice, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#Usage_notes

You said you would like to learn as you go, but trying something more systematic might help you avoid running into situations like this. [freeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/) seems like an awesome place, otherwise you could also find free HTML/CSS/JavaScript courses on Coursera, Udacity, edX, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Say I wanted to do it with JS or JQuery for an example and make it look something like this, https://ibb.co/FwZKRft is there like a tutorial or a document I could know what to search up? Idk what this part of coding is called

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understand your problem. Approaching this kind of issue with custom code can be extremely time consuming. Fortunately there's a huge amount of great JQuery plugins out there which will provide a solution. The majority of websites out there with this kind of functionality will never use custom code, they'll use image sliders. You can achieve what you're looking for by using these. Checkout Slick Slider by Ken Wheeler - https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you know where I could learn/read a documentation on something like this? https://ibb.co/FwZKRft The image link I posted is what I wanted my website to look mainly.

Comment: All the documentation can be found on the link i provided above. Its extensive and also includes multiple examples